# How to remove lines from a file that are sub-strings of other lines

Tags: python, string, for-loop

Here is a file where many lines are sub-strings of other lines. How could I filter it to include only the longest version of each line?

```
buffer not
buffer not available
code 000001
error pxa_no_shared_memory
error pxa_no_shared_memory occurred
error pxa_no_shared_memory occurred short
error pxa_no_shared_memory occurred short dump
failed return
failed return code
failed return code 000001
for pxa
for pxa buffer
for pxa buffer not
for pxa buffer not available
initialization runt
initialization runt failed
initialization runt failed return
initialization runt failed return code
initialization runt failed return code 000001
memory for
memory for pxa
memory for pxa buffer
memory for pxa buffer not
memory for pxa buffer not available
not available
occurred short
occurred short dump
```

If the short phrase occurs in a longer phrase, like "buffer not" also occurs in "buffer not available" and "memory for pxa buffer not available", I WANT TO KEEP THE "memory for pxa buffer not available".

The output should be a text file containing all the longest error messages.
Like this:

```
error pxa_no_shared_memory occurred short dump
initialization runt failed return code 000001
memory for pxa buffer not available
```

Comment: I don't understand why people downvote questions so often.  This seems like an interesting problem to me.

Comment: What computational complexity is required?

Comment: there is no computational complexity required. thanks

Comment: @intrepidhero It gets downvoted because it doesn't show ANY effort at all. It's just a dump of requirements, asking Stack Overflow to do their work for them.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Thanks for explaining. I'm kind of new and have been confused by down votes with no explanation. Woudl you say this is a case of insufficient effort? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40971/new-reason-for-closing-insufficient-effort

Comment: @intrepidhero Pretty much, yes. Questions get downvoted and closed when they don't show effort. Note that it is also on the tooltip on the downvote button: "This question does not show any research effort".

Comment: @S.L.Barth Ah! I learn something every day. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about efficiency but:

```
with open('lines.txt') as f:
    original = f.read().splitlines()
    results = set(original)
    for o in original:
        for r in set(results):
            if o != r:
                try:
                    if o in r:
                        results.remove(o)
                    elif r in o:
                        results.remove(r)
                except KeyError:
                    pass

print('\n'.join(results))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
phrases = '''buffer not
buffer not available
code 000001
error pxa_no_shared_memory
error pxa_no_shared_memory occurred
error pxa_no_shared_memory occurred short
error pxa_no_shared_memory occurred short dump
failed return
failed return code
failed return code 000001
for pxa
for pxa buffer
for pxa buffer not
for pxa buffer not available
initialization runt
initialization runt failed
initialization runt failed return
initialization runt failed return code
initialization runt failed return code 000001
memory for
memory for pxa
memory for pxa buffer
memory for pxa buffer not
memory for pxa buffer not available
not available
occurred short
occurred short dump'''.split("\n")

""" We want to find only the longest versions of each line """

results = []
for phrase in phrases:
    found = -1
    # check to see if there is a version of this phrase we've encountered already
    for i, r in enumerate(results):
        # if our new phrase is longer then replace the existing version
        if phrase.startswith(r) and len(phrase) > len(r):
            found = i
            break
        # if the existing version is longer than do nothing
        elif r.startswith(phrase):
            found = -2
            break
    if found == -2:
        continue
    elif found > -1:
        results[found] = phrase
    else:
        # otherwise it must be a new phrase
        results.append(phrase)
```

Not exactly elegant but gets the job done.